# path variables in react api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, fetch-api

I have an API that responds to an API call like below in Postman:
[image: Postman]

The body is just

```
"username": "bobmarley"
```

How can I replicate this in my React/Next project?

Here is what I currently have:

```js
export async function getUser(data) {
  
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/users/:username`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })

  var response_data = await response.json();

  return(response_data);
}
```

How can I pass these path variables like in Postman too?

**UPDATE**

I implemented changes like comments suggested but came across issues:

```
export async function getUser(data) {

  const username = data
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/users/${username}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({username: username})
  })
  var response_data = await response.json();
  
  return(response_data);
}
```

This throws an error:

```
http://localhost:4000/users/bobmarley 404 (Not Found)
```

Not sure what to do?

**UPDATE 2**

I changed POST to GET but I got this error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.
```

I had GET in postman with the body below and it worked fine.

```
{
    "username": "bobmarley"
}
```

Comment: Have you actually implemented the API route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to pass it in in the string itself, like:

```
export async function getUser(data) {

  const username = data.username //fake, but something like that i guess
  
  // and then use template string notation `regular string ${jsInterpolation}`
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/users/${username}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
  var response_data = await response.json();

  return(response_data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:username` is called a request parameter, Postman parses it for you behind the scene when you specify the value within those boxes.

However, working with React, you need to specify the value of the username in your fetch URL.

So it should look like this:

```js
http://localhost:4000/users/bobmarly
```

As opposed to this

```js
http://localhost:4000/users/:username
```

So if you have the `username` in the `data` you're passing into the `getUser()` function then specify it in the fetch URL using template strings in javascript.

Like this

```js
const username = data.username || 'bobmarley';

const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/users/${username}`, {
  ...
})
```

Comment: Change your method from "POST" to "GET"

Comment: With GET requests, you don't need that body anymore. Remove  line `this body: JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: In fact change all of this `await fetch(...)` line to just `await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/users/${username}`)`

Answer (score 1):

The others got it, so just piggy-backing here.

Your API should be parsing the query string. That is, it looks like you've setup your API to *need* to look at the `/:username` part of the query string. Alternatively, you could pass it in the body, but that's outside the scope of your question. Here's an example, given your constraints.

```js
export async function getUser({ username = 'bobmarley', ...rest }) {
  
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/users/${username}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify(rest)

  });

  const response_data = await response.json();

  return response_data;
}
```

Unless you're passing other data in the body, you can destructure the data argument to its `username` property. If you *are* passing or require other body data, though, make sure your API endpoint is setup to deal with that type of data, too (I left the `JSON.stringify` part, for reference).